# How V8 handles this/dict?

Tags: javascript, v8

From V8 presentations, I know that it optimizes constructions like this with tagging a type object:

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

What happens in the case I return an object (JSON), without using `this`? Will V8 apply the same optimization?

```
function parse() {
  ...
  // Suppose error happened (some branch of logic):
  return {
    pos: i,
    message: 'ka-boom'
  };
  ...
  // Everything is OK:
  return {
    value: 42
  };
}
```

In the sample above, will V8 tag with types objects (so, member access have chance to be real fast) or leave as maps? Note different paths return different objects.

Comment: Your plain objects have nothing to do with JSON by the way. JSON === string or sequence of characters which respects a subset of the JavaScript Object Notation defined in the JSON spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object literals get same optimization for the properties that are introduced inside the literal (not outside).

Constructed objects right now additionally get up to 8 properties that can be introduced outside without penalty. This means subclasses can call parent constructor without worry for up to 8 properties. However **optional** introduction of properties is still bad of course.

However, if your object literals require functions or other immutable heavy-weight data, not using prototypes will cost you dearly.

Also in these cases the object will not yet necessarily become a hash table but the properties will just be placed in an external array. This is slower than Java/C++-like objects which they are in fastest mode but not as slow as the slowest hash table mode.

So there is 3 modes of storage: fast in-object (like C++/Java objects), fastish out-of-object (no example), slow hashtable (like PHP, Python, Ruby in their canonical implementations)